# Jenkins job DSL guard-rescue in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-build-flow

Lately, I'm working on a project where I'm swapping deprecated build flows to build pipeline in several job DSL generated Jenkins.
One particular problem was to swap the build [flows guard-rescue mechanism](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) to pipeline syntax. I'm curious what you think about my solution:

See the following flow DSL:

```
guard {
    b = build("parameterised_job")
} rescue {
    build("analyzer_job",
        PARAMETER_ONE:b.environment.get("PARAMETER_ONE"),
        PARAMETER_TWO:b.environment.get("PARAMETER_TWO")
        )
}
```

I created the following alternative with the pipeline syntax:

```
pipeline {
agent any 
    stages {
        stage("build") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def b = build(job: "parameterised_job", propagate: false)
                    build(job: "analyzer_job",
                    parameters:
                    [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PARAMETER_ONE', value: b.buildVariables.PARAMETER_ONE],
                    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PARAMETER_TWO', value: b.buildVariables.PARAMETER_TWO]])
                    if(b.result == 'FAILURE') {
                        error("${b.projectName} FAILED")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```